# Spring Boot using record clas to store metadata in .yml file not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm trying to read metadata in .yml file then injecting values in record class, finally use those value in other classes.

I have a application.yml file with value:

```
teamson:
    clientId: 123
    clientSecret: 456
    tenantId: 789
```

hava a GaphConfig.java :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "teamson")
public record GraphConfig(String clientId, String clientSecret, String tenantId) {
}
```

and want to use metadata value in tryRead.java:

```
@Component
public class tryRead {

@Autowired
private static GraphConfig cofig;

    public static void main(String arts[]){
    
       System.out.println(cofig.clientId());
    
    }

}
```

but always get error  : Cannot invoke "com.xxx.GraphConfig.clientId()" because "com.xxx.tryRead.cofig" is null

I have included depedency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

I use JAVA 17 and SpringBoot Version 2.7.14

I want
System.out.println(cofig.clientId()); in class tryRead can read id that set in properties.yml
and also reusable in other spring classes

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to inject via `@Autowired` to static field which is not possible.

Comment: Why does a `@Component` have a main method?

Comment: @FilipRistic thanks for reply, that I actually noticed, 
however, although I use a  `@RestController` class and use constructor injection the clientId,    
then test it by a `@GetMapping`, it won't work either, still read null.
On the contrary,  `@autowired` works if I autowired another Component that set directly an id value in member like : 
  
        `public String coachid = "123";`
 
meaning that there are other reasons leading to read .yml data failure.

Comment: @FilipRistic thanks for the reply, just wanna try any method run and print out to see if iD can be autowired and read from .yml

Answer (score 0):

Finally...I found out what happened to this question, it's my typo : "appication.yml" , since Spring Boot can only read the name "application.yml".

However, this begs another question that I've been finding the answer to for a while: Is there a way for me to read any named yml file ?? e.g. if I want to use "config-dev.yml" or "config-prod.yml" to read different values with same property's name for development version or production version.

Comment: probably best to ask your new questions as a new post